# when use Boost to handle json string, I get a core dump which say "stream is not available"

Tags: c++, json, boost, jsonreader

I use boost to handle a Json, it works well, but today I get a core.
here is the stack.

```
#0  0x0000000000517a19 in std::for_each<std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >**, std::vector<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*, std::allocator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*> > > >, std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*> > > (__first=
    {<std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*,ptrdiff_t,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >**,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*&>> = {<No data fields>}, current = {_M_current = 0x7fcb5d7a1268}}, __last=
    {<std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*,ptrdiff_t,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >**,boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*&>> = {<No data fields>}, current = {_M_current = 0x7fcb5d7a1260}}, __f=
  {<std::unary_function<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*,int>> = {<No data fields>}, op = {<std::binary_function<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*,boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*,int>> = {<No data fields>}, _M_f = {__pfn = 0x1, __delta = 0}}, value = 0x4121a440}) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_function.h:664
#1  0x000000000051b819 in ~grammar (this=0x4121a440) at bc_out/third-64/boost/output/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/impl/grammar.ipp:103
#2  0x000000000051ef46 in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json_internal<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=Variable "stream" is not available.
)
    at bc_out/third-64/boost/output/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:310
#3  0x000000000051f2ed in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=Variable "stream" is not available.
)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/ext/new_allocator.h:69
```

and this is my code.

```
 std::stringstream stream;
 boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
 char *strs = (char *)(row->get_value(json_it->src_index));
 if (strs == NULL) {
      continue;
 }

 std::string strJson = strs;
 stream << strJson;
 try {
        //crash on this row
           boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json<boost::property_tree::ptree>(stream, pt);
        } catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_error &e) {
            REPORT_WARNING("read json fail: %s, error:%s", strJson.c_str(), e.what());
            continue;  
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            REPORT_WARNING("read json fail: %s, error:%s", strJson.c_str(), e.what());
            continue; 
        } catch (...) {
            REPORT_WARNING("read json fail: %s", strJson.c_str());
            continue; 
        }
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, anyone can help me?

Comment: the "not available" part is most likely the source code for showing you what is going on at that position in the stack trace.  As for why it's crashing, I don't see any code that you listed that obviously corresponds to anything in that stack trace, so I don't know.

Comment: You are right, the "not available" is not important. I have given more information on this question. Is there any mistakes in those codes? I think it's the invalid Json string, which makes the program crashed. But for some reasons, I can't replay this. Thank you!